# Getting the sequence number used as default value in insert in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a sequence:

```
create sequence mainseq as bigint start with 1 increment by 1
```

that I use to populate the primary key of a table:

```
create table mytable(
    id      bigint not null constraint DF_MYTABLE_ID default next value for mainseq,
    code    varchar(20) not null
)
```

If I insert into the table like this:

```
insert into mytable(code) values('hello')
```

how do I know the ID generated by the sequence? Something like `select scope_identity()` when using identity.

I don't think it is safe to get the last number from:

```
select current_value from sys.sequences where name = 'mainseq'
```

because some other query may have change it. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177564.aspx)

```
INSERT INTO mytable
            (code)
OUTPUT      INSERTED.id
VALUES     ('hello');
```

Though for some cases you may find it more convenient simply to call the sequence directly

```
DECLARE @id BIGINT;

SELECT @id = next value for mainseq;

INSERT INTO mytable
            (id,
             code)
VALUES     (@id,
            'hello'); 

SELECT @id;
```

Comment: Oh my god, where have I been? Output clause is available since SQL 2005!